# DatePickerRange customization

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have general example of DatePickerRange from plotly Dash.
I am looking for alternative that I can use on my Dash dashboard, or solution which will allow me to :

1. change `DatePickerRange` box size
2. change `DatePickerRange` font style and size
3. also I have a problem, when `start date` is selected I don't see calendar pop-up for this date, but I can see `last available date` pop up , and to select again `start date` I need to manually move to the beginning of calendar again.
   So problem to solve here is to shot calendar shortcut for each
   current minimum and maximum date when selected, not only for last
   date

Thanks, in advice

```
    app = dash.Dash(__name__)
    app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
         id='my-date-picker-range',
         min_date_allowed=date(1995, 8, 5),
         max_date_allowed=date(2017, 9, 19),
        initial_visible_month=date(2017, 8, 5),
        end_date=date(2017, 8, 25)
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-container-date-picker-range')
     ])
    
    
    @app.callback(
       Output('output-container-date-picker-range', 'children'),
        Input('my-date-picker-range', 'start_date'),
        Input('my-date-picker-range', 'end_date'))
     def update_output(start_date, end_date):
       string_prefix = 'You have selected: '
       if start_date is not None:
         start_date_object = date.fromisoformat(start_date)
         start_date_string = start_date_object.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
         string_prefix = string_prefix + 'Start Date: ' + start_date_string + ' | '
    if end_date is not None:
        end_date_object = date.fromisoformat(end_date)
        end_date_string = end_date_object.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
        string_prefix = string_prefix + 'End Date: ' + end_date_string
    if len(string_prefix) == len('You have selected: '):
        return 'Select a date to see it displayed here'
    else:
        return string_prefix
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Edit : problem 1 and 2 solved by using style in `html.Div([], style={"width":"" ,"height":"","font-size":""})` as parent of RangePickerDate